# No package metadata was found for supervisor 4.2.2 on Debian11

Tags: debian, supervisord

I'm trying to install and use supervisor with Debian 11.
I run Python3.11 but have tested with Python3.10 as well without success. (Python is built from source)

```
Setting up supervisor (4.2.2-2) is succesful
```

But when I run supervisorctl to manage the processes I get the following error:
Have tried to upgrade/downgrade PIP
Have tried to install python3 importlib package separately.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/**init**.py", line 563,
> in from_name
> return next(cls.discover(name=name))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ StopIteration
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl",
> line 33, in 
> sys.exit(load_entry_point('supervisor==4.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'supervisorctl')())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
> for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/**init**.py", line 981,
> in distribution
> return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/**init**.py", line 565,
> in from_name
> raise PackageNotFoundError(name) importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found
> for supervisor

If I try to install importlib-metadata:

```
pip install importlib-metadata
```

I get other error:

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
> line 786, in resolve
> raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pip._vendor.pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.3.4'
> distribution was not found and is required by the application

And I tried downgrading PIP to 20.3.4 and tried installing supervisor using PIP

and got into a different error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py",
> line 556, in **get**
> ret = obj.**dict**[self._fname] = self._f(obj)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
> 1014, in _lsb_release_info
> stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
> return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')'
> returned non-zero exit status 1.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it globally with pip (not in an environment).